# If I answer my own question, do I get credited on my acceptance rate?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

If I answer my own question, do I get credited on my acceptance rate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to accept one answer whether it's your own or not. Otherwise your acceptance rate would decrease. Therefore yes, you are credited on your acceptance rate if you select your own answer as best.

However, as mentioned by Gamecat, you won't get any Rep points.

Comment: you must be a programmer ;-). Yes he asked for credit but it was obvious he meant rep points.

Comment: @Gamecat: Yes, I am a programmer :)

Comment: @Gamecat: "Yes he asked for credit but it was obvious he meant rep points."  He asked about credit on **acceptance rate**.  Since acceptance rate has nothing to do with rep, that would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't give yourself any rep points. Else it was extremely easy to get an enormous amount of rep points.

Comment: He's asking specifically about the calculation of the "acceptance rate" (i.e. does self-accept count as having accepted an answer), not giving himself reputation points.